# Wireguard Internet Only clients + LAN/Internet Clients

Tags: iptables, docker, wireguard

I have a Wireguard installation running based on the docker image linuxserver/wireguard.
It's running on a Ubuntu 20.04 host.

The speed is good and the my client can connect from both my local LAN and from the Internet gaining access to both local LAN and internet in both situations. So far so good.

Now I want to add a second type of clients. These clients should *only* have internet access when connected to the VPN. The restriction must be configured on the server. Also I would like the clients to use my LAN's DNS server (pihole). I realize that the clients would be able to perform LAN DNS lookups and exposing LAN IP's of services on the LAN. That is OK for now. The important thing is that the traffic cannot be routed to LAN hosts and services.

```
Network range 192.168.X.0 - 192.168.X.255
My router IP: 192.168.X.1
Pihole IP: 192.168.X.Y
```

**wg0.conf (which is generated by the linuxserver/wireguard image)**

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.13.13.1
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = XXXXX
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
PublicKey = XXXXX
AllowedIPs = 10.13.13.2/32

[Peer]
PublicKey = XXXXX
AllowedIPs = 10.13.13.3/32
```

Comment: Perhaps have two wireguard images running, one for each type of client?

Comment: I have considered this and it might be the way to go. It doesn't seem like an optimal solution though.

Comment: For me optimal is the simplest to set up and maintain, when performance is the same.

Comment: How would the config look for an Internet Only setup ?

Answer (score 0):

Attach the 'Internet only' container to a [macvlan network](https://docs.docker.com/network/macvlan/).

Once the macvlan is created and the container running, you basically have a new machine (with its own MAC Address) sending packet thru your physical host interface.

The macvlan can be [created on a vlan interface](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-macvlan/#8021q-trunked-bridge-example) if needed. From that point, you can isolate the container from the rest of your network as appropriate, as you'll do for a regular host.

[edit](It *might be* possible to create a docker default bridge network on top of a vlan interface you set up yourself on the host but using macvlan saves you from that last task).

[docker](/questions/tagged/docker) [macvlan](/questions/tagged/macvlan)

Comment: So basically your idea is to create a second container as well or do I miss a point ?

Comment: Yes. Right.

Unless you can have wireguard to safely isolate traffic to the macvlan network you would attach to your first container.
Might be possible, didn't check.